# Can HighChart/HTML5 Chart be exported as HTML in Jasperreport

Tags: java, highcharts, jasper-reports

I am working on a desktop application, which is supported to be able to show report.

I am planning to export the report as html first and load the html by webview.

To implement this fucntion, I use jasperreports-highcharts-6.2.0.jar.

But I still can't export any reports which contain Highcharts/HTML5 Chart.

There is my code:

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("htmlPath");
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
HtmlExporter html = new HtmlExporter();
html.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jrPrint));
html.setExporterOutput(new SimpleHtmlExporterOutput(pw));
try {
    html.exportReport();
    pw.flush();
    pw.close();
} catch (JRException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

There is the error:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.highcharts.charts.ChartHtmlHandler.generateChartHtml(ChartHtmlHandler.java:150)
    at com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.highcharts.charts.ChartHtmlHandler.getHtmlFragment(ChartHtmlHandler.java:63)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.HtmlExporter.writeGenericElement(HtmlExporter.java:1425)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.HtmlExporter$CellElementVisitor.visit(HtmlExporter.java:2614)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.HtmlExporter$CellElementVisitor.visit(HtmlExporter.java:2528)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRTemplateGenericPrintElement.accept(JRTemplateGenericPrintElement.java:163)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.HtmlExporter$TableVisitor.visit(HtmlExporter.java:2499)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.HtmlExporter$TableVisitor.visit(HtmlExporter.java:2483)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.tabulator.ElementCell.accept(ElementCell.java:56)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.HtmlExporter.exportTable(HtmlExporter.java:590)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.HtmlExporter.writeLayers(HtmlExporter.java:1472)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.HtmlExporter$TableVisitor.visit(HtmlExporter.java:2523)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.HtmlExporter$TableVisitor.visit(HtmlExporter.java:2483)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.tabulator.LayeredCell.accept(LayeredCell.java:64)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.HtmlExporter.exportTable(HtmlExporter.java:590)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.HtmlExporter.exportPage(HtmlExporter.java:493)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.HtmlExporter.exportReportToWriter(HtmlExporter.java:385)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.HtmlExporter.exportReport(HtmlExporter.java:239)
    at com.legendapl.lightning.controller.W04InputControlController.report(W04InputControlController.java:1781)
    at com.legendapl.lightning.controller.W04InputControlController.initialize(W04InputControlController.java:273)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)
    at com.legendapl.lightning.controller.C00ControllerBase.showPane(C00ControllerBase.java:147)
    at com.legendapl.lightning.controller.P02RepoController.showReportPane(P02RepoController.java:647)
    at com.legendapl.lightning.controller.P02RepoController.lambda$23(P02RepoController.java:619)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.postProcess(Scene.java:3470)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.access$8100(Scene.java:3398)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3766)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:381)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:417)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:78)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:97)
    at org.apache.commons.collections.ExtendedProperties.load(ExtendedProperties.java:542)
    at org.apache.commons.collections.ExtendedProperties.load(ExtendedProperties.java:518)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.setDefaultProperties(RuntimeInstance.java:416)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.initializeProperties(RuntimeInstance.java:628)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.init(RuntimeInstance.java:261)
    at org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine.init(VelocityEngine.java:93)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.web.util.VelocityUtil.<clinit>(VelocityUtil.java:58)
    ... 58 more
```

Could you please give me some advice?